# how to pass two gridview textbox values to a javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

hi,i am new to javascript,

my problem is i have a simple date check function as follow

```
function CompareDates(str1, str2) 
   {
          var dt1 = parseInt(str1.substring(0, 2), 10);
          var mon1 = parseInt(str1.substring(3, 5), 10);
          var yr1 = parseInt(str1.substring(6, 10), 10);
          var dt2 = parseInt(str2.substring(0, 2), 10);
          var mon2 = parseInt(str2.substring(3, 5), 10);
          var yr2 = parseInt(str2.substring(6, 10), 10);
          var date1 = new Date(yr1, mon1, dt1);
          var date2 = new Date(yr2, mon2, dt2);

          if (date2 < date1) {
                alert("To date cannot be greater than from date");
                return false;
          }
          else
          {
                return true;
          } 

      }
```

**In Gridview**

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Start Dtae">
                           <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StartDate") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="txtStartDate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy"                 Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtStartDate"></asp:CalendarExtender>
                            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="End Dtae">
                           <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EndDate") %>' **onchange="CompareDates(txtStartDate.Text,this.Text)**;" ></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="txtEndDate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtEndDate">**strong text**</asp:CalendarExtender>
                           </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
```

grid is dynamic and user can add any number of rows to it. 
my need is to check the date without looping the entire gridview rows on submit button click. onchange of the txtenddate i want to pass the values of both text boxes..

can anybody help me..

Thank You..

Comment: Please specify more...If you want to check the textbox value on submit then yu have to apply the loop..Instead that how can you check the value

Comment: i want to pass both values to the function and then check. For that am confuced how to pass the textbox values. or instead can i pass the text boxes itself so that i can full fill my need

Answer (score 1):

Use `GridView_RowDataBound` event of gridview and on attributes you can attach the javascript `onchange` event

```
void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            TextBox txtStartDate = e.Row.FindControl("txtStartDate") as TextBox;
            TextBox txtEndDate= e.Row.FindControl("txtEndDate") as TextBox;

            txtEndDate.Attributes.Add("onchange", "CompareDates('" + txtStartDate.ClientID+ "', '" +txtEndDate.ClientID+ "');");
        }
}
```

}

And in your javascript function

```
function CompareDates(ctrlStartID, ctrlEndID) 
{ 
   var startDate = document.getElementByID(ctrlStartID).value; 
   var endDate = document.getElementByID(ctrlEndID).value; 
   //your further code
}
```

Comment: but the parameter is null.. ie the value at the row data bound. parameter passing is not working.

Comment: have you bind the datasorce to ur gridview?

Comment: The parameter is null in javascript..??
Is your RowDataBound event working. If yes check in browser the code rendered for Textboxes.

Comment: try 
"CompareDates('"+ txtStart.ClientID +"','"+ txtEnd.ClientID +"')";

Comment: in javascript

function CompareDates(ctrlStartID, ctrlEndID)
{
    var str1 = document.getElementByID(ctrlStartID);
    var str2 = document.getElementByID(ctrlEndID);
    
}

Comment: i did as you suggested but nothing happens..i also tried by passing  textbox clinetid and changed the function respectively bt function is invoked there after no response.

Comment: @AnishKarunakaran i have updated my answer, it may resolve ur problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code

```
TextBox txtStartDate = yourGridViewName.SelectedRow.FindControl("txtStartDate") as TextBox;
TextBox txtEndDate = yourGridViewName.SelectedRow.FindControl("txtEndDate") as TextBox;
```

Then you can get text as normally:

```
 string startDate = txtStartDate.Text;
 string endDate = txtEndDate .Text;
```

Please consider that follwong code is **not tested**. You can try RowDataBound event of GridView to add JavaScript function

```
protected void yourGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
         //Get TextBoxes
         TextBox txtStartDate = yourGridViewName.SelectedRow.FindControl("txtStartDate") as TextBox;
         TextBox txtEndDate = yourGridViewName.SelectedRow.FindControl("txtEndDate") as TextBox;

         //Get text
         string startDate = txtStartDate.Text;
         string endDate = txtEndDate .Text;

         //Assign the function
         e.Row.Attributes.Add("Onchange", "CompareDates('" + startDate + "', '" + endDate + "'");
    }
}
```

Comment: But how can i call javascript function with this values.. Onchange event is invoking the js function.. i can add the function to each text box on row databound.. but what about the parameters?

Comment: please provide, Onchange event of GridViewRow?

Comment: but the parameter is null.. ie the value at the row data bound. parameter passing is not working.

Comment: i did as you suggested but nothing happens..i also tried by passing textbox clinetid and changed the function respectively bt function is invoked there after no response

Comment: sorry, but I can't help you further.

Answer (score 0):

The best method I would suggest you is to add the Row_DataBound and in this event read the rows and add the change event programmatically.

void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {

```
if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
            Textbox text1 = ((Textbox )e.Row.FindControl("Textbox1"));
            Textbox text2 = ((Textbox )e.Row.FindControl("Textbox2"));
            text2 .Attributes.Add("onfocus", "EventName('"+text1 .Text+"','"+text1.Text+"')"+);


}
```

}

Comment: but the parameter is null.. ie the value at the row data bound. parameter passing is not working.

Comment: i did as you suggested but nothing happens..i also tried by passing  textbox clinetid and changed the function respectively bt function is invoked there after no response.

Comment: We are missing single quotes in parameters

 TextBox text1 = ((TextBox )e.Row.FindControl("Textbox1"));
                 TextBox text2 = ((TextBox )e.Row.FindControl("Textbox2"));
                 text2.Attributes.Add("onblur", "EvName('" + text1.Text + "','" + text2.Text + "')");

Change the Attribute line by adding quotes around parameters. Its working I have tested.